# Redirect multiple print output to single file in json format using python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I have used boto3 to read and print metadata from s3 bucket. As a next step i want to redirect the printed output in a json file and write the json file to s3 bucket. The printed output has 2 fields author and timestamp. I need to append both the printed outputs in 1 file in json format.

Comment: Ok, so where is you current python code? Why it does not work? What errors do you get?

Comment: i have written my python code as part of aws lambda. I am new to python so was looking for reference to achieve this.